# Jhipster jdl error - `Valid source and destination entities are required`

Tags: java, jhipster, jdl

I am trying to import my jdl file into my jhipster project but I am getting the following error:

```
$ jhipster import-jdl ./Assets/jhipster-jdl.jh --serverOnly
Using JHipster version installed globally
Executing jhipster:import-jdl ./Assets/jhipster-jdl.jh
Options: serverOnly: true, server-only: true
The JDL is being parsed.
Error: Valid source and destination entities are required.
ERROR! ERROR! Error while parsing applications and entities from the JDL Error: Valid source and destination entities are required.
Error: ERROR! Error while parsing applications and entities from the JDL Error: Valid source and destination entities are required.
    at Environment.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:157:40)
    at module.exports.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:1978:18)
    at module.exports.importJDL (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/import-jdl/index.js:115:14)
    at new ImporterGenerator (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/import-jdl/index.js:80:38)
    at new module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/import-jdl/index.js:122:9)
    at Environment.instantiate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:408:12)
    at Environment.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:386:17)
    at Environment.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:443:28)
    at runYoCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/cli.js:63:13)
    at Command.command.allowUnknownOption.description.action (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/cli.js:83:13)
```

It's saying that I don't have a valid jdl file to be imported. Looking at my jdl, I can't find any syntactical errors and the error message does not give me a line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This error message is returned when [one of of the entities in relationships is invalid](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-core/blob/fe6614892f03cf02b9baf84a17546ea93140a605/test/spec/core/jdl_relationship_test.js#L44-L72).  Check the `relationship` sections of your JDL, make sure the entities on both sides of the relationship exist and are spelled correctly.